# Common Lisp: How to get (in-package ...) to work from within Emacs Slime

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime, ccl, eval-when

64-bit Windows 7 
Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.9 WindowsX8632 
Emacs 24.3.1 
Slime changelog date 2014-06-17

I have an example .lisp file which starts out as follows:

```
(ql:quickload 'qt)
(in-package "QT")
```

The rest of the program shows a dialog box.
When I run this from the command line, `wx86cl -load helloqt.lisp` it seems to work fine.
When I run this from Emacs Slime (`C-x C-k`) it says there is no package "QT". 
However if I first evaluate the first line individually (`C-x C-e`) then I can compile the whole thing and it works, modulo the normal issues of trying to run a QT thread from within Slime on Windows.

How do I make it so I can compile/run the file from emacs without having to manually evaluate the first line first?

Also, why doesn't `(in-package ...)` change the current package in the Slime session?  I have to change it manually if I want to interact with the package contents.

Comment: Very similar questions have been answered already. This won't be the last time. I've added a tag `eval-when`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you compile the file as a whole, it is first read as a whole.  At that time, none of it has yet been evaluated, so the package `QT` is not defined yet.

You can either use `eval-when` to evaluate something at an earlier time, or use a system definition facility (ASDF is predominant nowadays) to load your system in the right order.

`Eval-when`:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ql:quickload '#:qt))

(in-package #:qt)
```

Note that you usually should not muck around in library packages but define your own, fresh package to hold your code:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ql:quickload '#:qt))

(defpackage #:qt-example
  (:use #:qt))

(in-package #:qt-example)

;; your code here
```

*(In case you are wondering, `defpackage`, `defun`, `defclass` etc. are specially designed macros that expand to a form inside such an `eval-when`.)*

This is sometimes OK for little one-off scripts.  For systems of any noteworthy size, especially as soon as they have more than one source file, use ASDF:

```
;;;; qt-example.asd

(in-package #:cl-user)

(asdf:defsystem #:qt-experiments
  :description "Some experiments with QT."
  :serial t
  :components ((:file "package")
               (:file "qt-example"))
  :depends-on (#:qt))

;;;; package.lisp

(defpackage #:qt-example
  (:use #:qt))

;;;; qt-example.lisp

(in-package #:qt-example)
```

ASDF comes with most open-source Common Lisp implementations.  You might need to set up the ASDF registry.  I like to have one or two base directories for all my local projects, so that I can just put the following into `~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf`:

```
(:source-registry
  (:tree (:home "devel"))
  (:tree (:home "src"))
  :inherit-configuration)
```

Then ASDF finds all systems defined below those directories.  In SLIME, you can just use `,load-system` or `,open-system` from the REPL with the system name to load it, resp. open all files in it, optionally loading it.

When compiling a single toplevel form (using `C-c C-c`) from a file, SLIME looks backward from there for an `in-package` form to find out what package it should assume.  Conventionally, you should only have a single `in-package` form per file, at its top.

A commonly useful shortcut is `C-c ~` in Lisp source files, which switches the REPL to the directory of the file and the effective package at point.

Answer (score 1):

A little hard to find, but there is `slime-repl-set-package`:

```
(defun slime-connected-hook-switch-to-stumpwm-package ()
  (slime-repl-set-package "STUMPWM"))

(add-hook #'slime-editing-mode-hook
          #'slime-connected-hook-switch-to-stumpwm-package)
```